# How do I parse multiple integers from a string

Tags: java

I have the following string: `"B:0123EH:0234ET:0444"` and I need to parse the integers `"0123; 0234; 0444"` into separate integers.

Comment: See: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

Answer (score 1):

Regex might be useful:

```
    String numbersStr[] = "B:0123EH:0234ET:0444".split("[A-Z]+:0");
    int numbers[] = new int[numbersStr.length - 1];

    for (int i = 1; i < numbersStr.length; i++) {
        numbers[i - 1] = Integer.parseInt(numbersStr[i]);
        System.out.println(numbers[i - 1]);
    }
```

Now you have an array of integers. And for @cricket_007 's comment. You can replace the pattern with `[^0-9]+`.

PS; This will only work if the pattern you mentioned above is recurring

Comment: Why not split on `[^0-9]`?

Comment: @cricket_007. Nice one. Good idea

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
String str = "B:0123EH:0234ET:0444";
String[] words = str.split("[^0-9]+");
for(String word : words )
  System.out.println(word);
```

It takes the original string and splits it into an array of words, using the regex delimiter for non-numeric values. Then use a for loop to print them out one by one.

Comment: Why the apostrophe in the regex?

Comment: @cricket_007 cause I suck at typing :P